# Data wrangling to create a matrix from lists

Tags: matrix, csv-format

I have a super simple data wrangling question that I can't seem to figure out (I am new to Mathematica). Basically I'm not sure what function to use. I have two parameters, `paramc3` and `paramS`, that I used to get the output, `values`, in previous code. I simply want to create a matrix, with column headings corresponding to each `paramS` value and rows corresponding to each `paramc3` value and then export as a CSV. I tried:

```
paramc3 = Table[c3, {c3, 0, 2, 0.1}];
paramS = Table[s, {s, 0, 1, 0.1}];
values = {{unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable,
     unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    unstable}, {0.19754659869364347`, 4.878410368867524`, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable}, {unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    4.64757211994509`, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable}, {unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, 5.58201356941801`, 3.059853547091468`, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable}, {unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable, 5.484947253911817`, 
    2.6379330262422918`, unstable, unstable, unstable}, {unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    0.794348167322319`, 4.708767525484398`, unstable, unstable, 
    unstable}, {unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, 5.507247245016035`, 2.3277428641553386`, 
    unstable, unstable}, {unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable, 4.5774724131840365`, 
    3.7729720387151344`, unstable, unstable}, {unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    4.7172200222598395`, unstable, unstable}, {unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    5.286941004368434`, unstable, unstable}, {unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    5.486421676853467`, unstable, unstable}, {unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    5.184287940321331`, 1.1581471747603866`, unstable}, {unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, 3.8276962693927357`, 2.0886269128201467`, 
    unstable}, {unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 2.835722444419939`, 
    unstable}, {unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 3.44873547223903`, 
    unstable}, {unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 3.956627333693203`, 
    unstable}, {unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 4.377732263494166`, 
    unstable}, {unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 4.723815230292599`, 
    unstable}, {unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 5.0020155840974025`, 
    unstable}, {unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 5.215774894883028`, 
    unstable}, {unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 
    unstable, unstable, unstable, unstable, 5.365136687453673`, 
    unstable}};
m = MatrixForm[{values}, {paramS}, {paramc3}]
Export["Desktop/matrix.csv", m, "CSV"]
```

along with other functions like Thread, Distribute etc. I feel like this should be super simple and yet I'm so stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Take a look at the documentation for `Prepend`, `Append` and `Transpose`.

Comment: Thank you Rohit for the guidance on which functions to explore.

Answer (score 3):

```
Export["matrix.csv", values, TableHeadings -> {paramc3, paramS}]
```

Answer (score 2):

One of possible ways:

```
out = Transpose@
  Prepend[Transpose@Prepend[values, paramS], Prepend[paramc3, ""]]

Export["matrix.csv", out, "CSV"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Domen! This works.